# btrfs broke itself without hardware problem? how to recover?

Tags: data-recovery, btrfs

I have a Manjaro KDE installation on a LUKS encrypted SSD formatted with BTRFS. The System is mostly up to date, last update was maybe a week or two ago.

It suddenly switched to read-only, with dmesg showing a few dozen errors like those:

```
parent transid verify failed on * wanted * found *
```

(Very annoying btw. that Firefox isn't able to load pages without a writeable disk, which was how I first noticed the problem)

I tried rebooting, the boot process ran into the same problem dropping me into a emergency root shell because of only beeing able to mount read-only.

Now I'm in a live-session booted via USB. I was able to backup all data (most was backed up anyway but just to be sure).

I tried repairing the filesystem so I don't have to reinstall the system, but nothing worked so far. I've tried:

```
# btrfs check --repair /dev/mapper/luks-455a911f-2d10-4548-a671-e1d4b8295bce 
enabling repair mode
WARNING:

        Do not use --repair unless you are advised to do so by a developer
        or an experienced user, and then only after having accepted that no
        fsck can successfully repair all types of filesystem corruption. Eg.
        some software or hardware bugs can fatally damage a volume.
        The operation will start in 10 seconds.
        Use Ctrl-C to stop it.
10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
Starting repair.
Opening filesystem to check...
Checking filesystem on /dev/mapper/luks-455a911f-2d10-4548-a671-e1d4b8295bce
UUID: 4dd8f7e8-5ffb-4405-b3d8-789ea877483d
[1/7] checking root items
parent transid verify failed on 429604962304 wanted 724347 found 724505
parent transid verify failed on 429604962304 wanted 724347 found 724505
Ignoring transid failure
parent transid verify failed on 429597687808 wanted 722745 found 724505
parent transid verify failed on 429597687808 wanted 722745 found 724505
Ignoring transid failure
ERROR: child eb corrupted: parent bytenr=449465008128 item=361 parent level=1 child bytenr=429597687808 child level=1
ERROR: failed to repair root items: Input/output error
```

also:

```
# btrfs scrub start /mnt/1/
scrub started on /mnt/1/, fsid 4dd8f7e8-5ffb-4405-b3d8-789ea877483d (pid=16297)
# btrfs scrub status /mnt/1/
UUID:             4dd8f7e8-5ffb-4405-b3d8-789ea877483d
Scrub started:    Tue Sep 21 11:31:18 2021
Status:           aborted
Duration:         0:00:01
Total to scrub:   446.54GiB
Rate:             2.47GiB/s
Error summary:    no errors found
```

dmesg output from btrfs scrub:

```
[Sep21 09:32] BTRFS info (device dm-1): scrub: started on devid 1
[  +1.497704] BTRFS error (device dm-1): parent transid verify failed on 429604962304 wanted 724347 found 724505
[  +0.001083] BTRFS info (device dm-1): scrub: not finished on devid 1 with status: -5
```

also:

```
# btrfs filesystem balance start -dusage=60 -musage=60 /mnt/1
ERROR: error during balancing '/mnt/1': Input/output error
There may be more info in syslog - try dmesg | tail
```

dmesg during balance:

```
[Sep21 09:34] BTRFS info (device dm-1): disk space caching is enabled
[  +0.000011] BTRFS info (device dm-1): has skinny extents
[  +0.175630] BTRFS info (device dm-1): enabling ssd optimizations
[  +6.367553] BTRFS error (device dm-1): csum mismatch on free space cache
[  +0.000004] BTRFS warning (device dm-1): failed to load free space cache for block group 19349372928, rebuilding it now
[  +0.001476] BTRFS error (device dm-1): space cache generation (724505) does not match inode (720863)
[  +0.000003] BTRFS warning (device dm-1): failed to load free space cache for block group 21496856576, rebuilding it now
[  +0.149606] BTRFS info (device dm-1): balance: start -dusage=60 -musage=60 -susage=60
[  +0.000677] BTRFS info (device dm-1): relocating block group 670257119232 flags data
[  +1.210621] BTRFS info (device dm-1): found 7370 extents, stage: move data extents
[  +0.033649] BTRFS error (device dm-1): parent transid verify failed on 429608239104 wanted 724347 found 724505
[  +0.007518] BTRFS info (device dm-1): balance: ended with status: -5
```

Since none of the dmesg lines look like hardware problems, I suspect it's just a btrfs bug that made it destroy itself... :(

Also, SMART looks good:

```
# nvme smart-log /dev/nvme0
Smart Log for NVME device:nvme0 namespace-id:ffffffff
critical_warning                        : 0
temperature                             : 39 C (312 Kelvin)
available_spare                         : 100%
available_spare_threshold               : 10%
percentage_used                         : 0%
endurance group critical warning summary: 0
data_units_read                         : 5,042,443
data_units_written                      : 11,709,865
host_read_commands                      : 34,269,040
host_write_commands                     : 109,286,265
controller_busy_time                    : 284
power_cycles                            : 482
power_on_hours                          : 417
unsafe_shutdowns                        : 13
media_errors                            : 0
num_err_log_entries                     : 1
Warning Temperature Time                : 0
Critical Composite Temperature Time     : 0
Thermal Management T1 Trans Count       : 0
Thermal Management T2 Trans Count       : 0
Thermal Management T1 Total Time        : 0
Thermal Management T2 Total Time        : 0
```

Comment: Hopefully you've got backups. This is exactly the reason why I don't use LVM or/and btrfs - both make data restoration near impossible. ext4 on the other hand is used in billions of devices (Google/Facebook servers, Android smartphones) and has a ton of tools to recover data or FS itself. Try your luck here: https://github.com/kdave/btrfs-progs/issues May 10 (!) report, https://github.com/kdave/btrfs-progs/issues/369 - no comments (!) from developers. 17 open bug reports about being unable to repair: https://github.com/kdave/btrfs-progs/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+repair

Comment: I do have backups and I can still mount the filesystem and read it, but I can't get it repaired so I guess I have to reinstall the system :( Which I'll probably do using luks+ext4 instead of luks+btrfs, though I really love the btrfs snapshot feature..

Comment: Considering that the FS maintainers themselves are not eager to fix issues in the rapair/fix code I guess it's your only option. It's unlikely anyone here will be able to help.

Comment: do you have any idea how this happened? Did you ever have power outages or anything like that?

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov no, I don't think so. It's a laptop with battery and while in use it just switched to read-only which made firefox not load any pages anymore. Tried rebooting & failed.